# IBM Worklight : Transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an eclipse workspace with an IBM worklight project running and I want to run another instance of eclipse with another worklight project on different ports. I have modified the server.xml which has the Http ports as follows:

```
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="10090" httpsPort="10453" id="defaultHttpEndpoint">
<tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>
```

and also the admin port as follows:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="10453"/>
```

But when I start the second server, I get the below error:

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]

Which port am I missing to change and where do I change that in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need to change the debug port for each server.

See here under "Java remote debug...": http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_dev_test_server_and_console.html

You need to open the jvm.options file in Eclipse > Servers > development server. Then edit the port number "10777" to a different one.

Comment: Thanks Idan, I am able to start the server on second eclipse now.